# The value is not valid put request

Tags: json, api, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm developing a web api using net core 5 and I'm getting the following error message after executing a put request from POSTMAN

> "errors": {
> "id": [
> "The value '44' is not valid."
> ]
> }

I have a breakpoint inside my controller method but doesn't hit any part of that code. So maybe this is a problem with the url that I'm using or some parameters configuration.

This is my httpmethod in my controller:

```
[HttpPut("Edit/{id}")]
public IActionResult Update(Guid id, [FromBody]Model mod)
{
    return mod.SomeValue;
}
```

And this is my request from POSTMAN:

```
https://localhost:8820/api/controller/Edit/44
```

I'm sending params from body as a JSON object (the same object works using my POST method)

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from using `Guid` type for storing a number.

you can't store 44 value in a `Guid` variable so change it to `int`.

```
[HttpPut("Edit/{id}")]
public IActionResult Update(int id, [FromBody]Model mod)
{
    return mod.SomeValue;
}
```